# W3 total cach and theme changes

Tags: theme-development, plugin-w3-total-cache

i have read that i have to weight with w3 total cache until my blog design is complete. But to be honest, it will never be finished. I'm constantly developing new stuff.

How will this affect my site if i chose to use w3 total cache? Can i reset the cache every time i make changes to the theme? and how does this plug in deal with comments?

Hope some one have a simple answer for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn it on and clear the cache whenever you like, it even adds a button to the admin bar specifically to purge all caches. I say implement it as early as possible so that you don't have to rewrite any code in case there's an odd conflict with it or anything. You can turn off comment caching if memory serves right, activate the plugin and just read through the options, it does a good job of explaining everything.

Answer (score 0):

HyperCache is similar plugin but much simpler and works really well! Very easy to turn off comment caching and clear the entire cache.